# Bigquery not updated with firestore database present in firebase after linking

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, google-cloud-firestore

may I know when I link my BigQuery (sandbox) with firebase, the collection that I have created manually in firestore, will it be added to BiqQuery? Or are there any steps to add it

I have a Spark account in my firebase, that I linked with big query
after linking of Firebase with BigQuery, 
will the data present in the firestore will be added automatically to BigQuery, will it require additional steps to do so

Comment: Hi, @paradox have you followed the steps described in this [link](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en) ? If something specific is not working please update your question with more details

Comment: @Tamir Klein, I have additional points please check it

Comment: Cloud Firestore is not automatically linked with BigQuery.  You will have to write code to make that connection yourself.

Comment: @ Doug Stevenson, okay, can I steps to do it